# React native partial modal

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, react-navigation

I am working on a react-native app using react navigation.

I want to add a partial modal that covers 30% of screen when pressing on one of the tabs in the bottom-tab, similar to the "+" tab in the YouTube app:

[Youtube modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDISC.jpg)

I've tried to use react-native Modal component, but

1. I have problems with activating it from bottom tab
2. it covers whole screen

Any suggestions?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question 100% correct I'd need to know more details about your project but, I can try to explain how can be your logic to do this withou any libs.
You can create another component called "Start" where you're gonna put your Modal with absolute position above your navigator.
You can create a Modal that will be above your navigator:

```js
export const Start(){

return(
 <View style={{flex:1}}>
   <Modal>
<View/>
   </Modal>
<NavigatorComponent/>
</View>
)
}
```

This is going to work because when you put a component with absolute position above the other, this component stay in front of the below component. In your case, will stay in front of everything including the TabBar.
To the modal has just 30% of the height you just need to put in its styles the attribute height: '30%'.

In the initial component of your App (usually the index.js file), you just return the new Start component.

I hope you like my answer. Please, if you have more questions you can ask. Waiting for your feedback :).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Actually, I have designed the modal. My problem is, how to activate it from the bottom tab bar using react navigation 5.

Comment: You're welcome :). Now, I got it. You can do something like this. ```<Tab.Screen
        name={'yourComponentName'}
        component={'yourComponent'}
    
        listeners={{
          tabPress: () => {
            //e.preventDefault(); // Use this to navigate somewhere else
           //This listener listen to every click you do in the tab icon. So here you can call your modal
        }}
      />``` Try this code and give me a feedback :).